# Count the id in JSON response with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I am getting below `JSON` response from a `REST` service-

```
[
   {
      "id":"cls102",
      "name":"Class X",
      "students":[
         {
            "total-students":38,
            "present-students":35
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"cls202",
      "name":"Class XI",
      "students":[
         {
            "total-students":42,
            "present-students":38
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

My objective is to get the total number of element `id`. I created model class which looks like below-

```
public class ClassRoom {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Student[] students;
    // Getter and Setter are not put here
}

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Student {
    @SerializedName("total-students")
    private int totalStudents;
    @SerializedName("present-students")
    private int presentStudents;
    // Getter and Setter are not put here
}
```

Now my test class is calling `Gson` in following fashion-

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
ClassRoom agents = gson.fromJson(jsonRepsone, ClassRoom.class);
```

Now, how to proceed further?

Comment: Is this different from the length of the top-level array?

Comment: I'm surprised you're getting a ClassRoom object out - you should be asking for an array of ClassRoom

Comment: @penguat: Just now started with `Gson`. Didn't get the proper documentation. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like this, because your JSON represents an array of `ClassRoom` objects.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
ClassRoom[] agents = gson.fromJson(jsonRepsone, ClassRoom[].class);

//Gives the no. of ClassRoom objects, which corresponds to the no.of `id`s
System.out.println(agents.length);
```

Comment: Can you please explain me about `ClassRoom[] testObj = new ClassRoom[0];` ? Why zero length array?

Comment: That's just a dummy object I've created. You need to pass the `Class` as the second parameter to `fromJson()` method, its for that purpose only. Else, it doesn't have any other significance.

Comment: Check the update. I've updated my answer. You needn't have that piece of code now.

Comment: You mean to iterate over `agents` array? Yes, you can. You can get each `ClassRoom` object and pull out relevant data as needed.

Comment: Yeah... I mean `for(ClassRoom class:agents){String id=class.getId();for(Student s:class.getStudents()){s.getTotalStudents();}}` Is this properway? or do I need to use `Gson` only?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27763/discussion-between-r-j-and-ravi-joshi)